# Can ransomware run without prompting user?

Tags: ransomware, uac

That is, a user downloads attachment from email and runs it, will the ransomware run silently without showing the security prompt/UAC (that should block non-administrator users...)

Comment: typically the user _is_ prompted before "_a user downloads attachment from email and runs it_"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ransomware wouldn't need to raise a UAC alert as it is after a user's personal files, not system files.